# Problem with the Terminal (ROS_DISTRO)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone!!

I have a problem with my Terminal, when I open it get this error:
ROS_DISTRO was set to 'fuerte' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.

And when I have used:
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash

Best,
Vincent

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62589/problem-with-the-terminal-(ros_distro)/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-05-12

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This warning just means that some of the ROS environment variables were already set when the */opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash* file was executed.  The most likely cause of this is an unintentional line in your *~/.bashrc* file.  If, for example, your *.bashrc* "sourced" the *setup.bash* for Fuerte before the one for Groovy, you would see this error.  Note that the unintentional line could possibly be in other bash startup scripts (such as *~/.profile*).

At any time, you can use `env |grep ROS` to see all of the ROS environment variables.  If none of them are pointing to Fuerte stuff, you are probably fine. Although, you should probably figure out the source of this warning and remove it anyway. Note you can always use the `unset` command to remove any stray environment variables.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2013-05-22**:
When I used: env |grep ROS

ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/common-lisp/ros

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

ROS_DISTRO=fuerte

ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/fuerte/etc/ros

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2013-05-22**:
I have two ROS groovy and fuerte